# virtual memory tlb misses

Tags: virtual-memory, tlb

i have the following code

```
 #define N 1024
    int A[N*N], B[N*N];int i,j;
    // Integers are 4 bytes
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        B[j*N+i] = A[i*N+j];
```

page size is 4kb ant TLB is direct-mapped with 1024 entries

I know that since an integer requires 4 bytes for storage and the page size is 4096 bytes, each array is stored in one page, represented as A[0...2013],B[0...1023] but I have a hard time finding the amount of TLB misses, can somebody help?